# TYPO3 Tabs on Page Properties

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

on the page properties in the main language are 7 tabs. On every translated page there are just 4 tabs. The "behavior" tab for example is hidden or missing. On this tab there is the field "link target" which I need in one specific project.

Is there a way to show this specific tab or just the field link target?

Thank's in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the palette (`TCA - table configuration array`) for the pages_language_overlay table and add the field. On top of that, you might need to configure the translation overlay for the link field.

For that you have to adjust the settings for the installation.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how it works, but I am pretty sure I did way too much. Anyway, it may help someone you facing the same challenge:

extTables.php

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['columns']['target']['config']['eval'] = 'trim';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['columns']['target']['config']['max'] = 80;
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['columns']['target']['config']['size'] = 50;
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['columns']['target']['config']['type'] = 'input';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['columns']['target']['exclude'] = 1;
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['columns']['target']['label'] = 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.target';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['interface']['showRecordFieldList'] = 'title,hidden,starttime,endtime,keywords,description,abstract,target';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['interface']['showRecordFieldList'] = 'title,hidden,starttime,endtime,keywords,description,abstract,target';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['palettes']['5']['showitem'] = 'author,author_email,target';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['palettes']['links']['canNotCollapse'] = 1;
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['palettes']['links']['showitem'] = 'alias;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.alias_formlabel, --linebreak--, target;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.target_formlabel, --linebreak--, url_scheme;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.url_scheme_formlabel';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['types']['1']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.external;external,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.title;title,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.visibility;visibility,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.access;access,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.metadata,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.abstract;abstract,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.editorial;editorial,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.appearance,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.layout;layout,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.behaviour,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.links;links,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.language;language,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.miscellaneous;miscellaneous,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.resources,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.media;media,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.storage;storage,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.config;config,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.extended, --div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['types']['3']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.external;external,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.title;title,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.visibility;visibility,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.access;access,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.metadata,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.abstract;abstract,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.editorial;editorial,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.appearance,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.layout;layout,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.behaviour,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.links;links,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.language;language,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.miscellaneous;miscellaneous,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.resources,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.media;media,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.storage;storage,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.config;config,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.extended, --div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['types']['4']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.external;external,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.title;title,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.visibility;visibility,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.access;access,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.metadata,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.abstract;abstract,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.editorial;editorial,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.appearance,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.layout;layout,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.behaviour,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.links;links,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.language;language,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.miscellaneous;miscellaneous,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.resources,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.media;media,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.storage;storage,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.config;config,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.extended, --div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['types']['7']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.external;external,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.title;title,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.visibility;visibility,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.access;access,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.metadata,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.abstract;abstract,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.editorial;editorial,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.appearance,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.layout;layout,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.behaviour,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.links;links,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.language;language,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.miscellaneous;miscellaneous,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.resources,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.media;media,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.storage;storage,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.config;config,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.extended, --div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['types']['199']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.external;external,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.title;title,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.visibility;visibility,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.access;access,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.metadata,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.abstract;abstract,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.editorial;editorial,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.appearance,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.layout;layout,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.behaviour,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.links;links,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.language;language,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.miscellaneous;miscellaneous,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.resources,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.media;media,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.storage;storage,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.config;config,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.extended, --div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['types']['254']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.external;external,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.title;title,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.visibility;visibility,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.access;access,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.metadata,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.abstract;abstract,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.editorial;editorial,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.appearance,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.layout;layout,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.behaviour,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.links;links,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.language;language,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.miscellaneous;miscellaneous,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.resources,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.media;media,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.storage;storage,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.config;config,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.extended, --div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages_language_overlay']['types']['255']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.external;external,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.title;title,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.visibility;visibility,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.access;access,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.metadata,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.abstract;abstract,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.editorial;editorial,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.appearance,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.layout;layout,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.behaviour,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.links;links,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.language;language,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.miscellaneous;miscellaneous,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.resources,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.media;media,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.storage;storage,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.palettes.config;config,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xlf:pages.tabs.extended, --div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories';
```